# Python Pandas: How does Axis Parameter Work in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, axis

**Background**:
In pandas, if I use the following:

```
df.sum(axis=1)
```

It returns sum of each row.

In the same manner, I expect the following to drop any row that contains missing value:

```
df.dropna(how='any', axis=1)
```

But the above code line actually drops any column that contains missing values rather than dropping rows with missing values.

**The Question:**   I understand why the first line returns sum of rows; but how come dropna(axis=1) drops columns?

=========
To clarify the question, I have provided the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (4, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

    A  B   C
0 NaN  9 4.0
1 8.0  8 1.0
2 5.0  3 6.0
3 3.0  3 NaN

df.sum(axis=1)
0   13.0
1   17.0
2   14.0
3    6.0

df.dropna(how='any', axis=1)
   B
0  9
1  8
2  3
3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.sum(axis=1)` returns the sum of all columns, that is, the sum of values in each column, and therefore it returns a row. `sum` aggerates and therefore reduces. When the values of the columns are all reduced, they are the ones being summed, and not the rows.

`df.sum(axis=0)` returns the sum of all rows where the cells are reduced row-wise.

`axis=1` reference the columns. `df.dropna(how='any', axis=1)` looks for `NaN` values and if a column contains one, it is dropped.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.  You have mistaken.  df.sum(axis=1) sums the rows, and I just tested it again to make certain that I'm not wrong.  So, what I have described in the question is accurate and the question remains.

Comment: This may be semantics issue. `df.sum(axis=1)` as you show is equivalent to *addition* or again *sum* of all columns: `df['A'] + df['B'] + df['C']` but skipping `NaN` as default. Think of the *direction* or *application* of running the `sum`. How? Over rows or across cols? As docs, mention [`DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) is the equivalent of `numpy.sum`.